# Android: Import render script to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, renderscript

I want import and use Render Script. But I get an error:

```
ScriptIntrinsicBlur cannot be resolved to a type
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Render script requires following tool

**Android SDK tools version 22.2**

**Android SDK Build-tools version 18.1.0**

First Open the project.properties file in your project and add following lines in the file

**renderscript.target=18**

**renderscript.support.mode=true**

**sdk.buildtools=18.1.0**

Now open your main class which use RenderScript and add an import for the Support Library classes as following

**import android.support.v8.renderscript.*;**

More Details:

renderscript.target->it is for byte code version to be generated

renderscript.support.mode->it is for a suitable  version for the generated byte code to fall back

sdk.buildtools->android sdk build tool version that we are going to use

thats it call your renderscript hope its helpful.

Comment: this is the proper  way use, refresh and  do it again the code has no error, the support library is mismatch did u delete v8 or replace v8 libarary if so it show error like this